# Add filter and export to excel in django app without using django tables-2

Tags: python, django, web

i need to add an option to filter data according to some column categories earlier i was using django tables_2 to display my table but that i was not able to filter data using that and decided tow rite my own view

my home.html looks like this

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Operating System</th>
            <th>Server Type (PHY/VM/LPAR)</th>
            <th>Version</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            {% if custom %}
            {% for item in custom %}
            <tr>
            <td>{{ item.name  }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Status}} </td>
            <td>{{ item.Product}}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Operating_System}}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Server_Type}}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Version}}</td>

        </tr>
            {% endfor %}

            {% else %}
                    there are no records
            {% endif %}   


    </tbody>
```

Now my table is displayed but I would like to give an option to filter data and also an option to export that to excel sheet after filtering 
how should i go about it ?